# How do I immediately use the value for each `yield()` of `AsyncStream`?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, actor

I am studying about swift concurrency.

I've been trying to write code that uses `AsyncStream` to load thumbnails and reflect them on the screen,
But what is the difference between the two codes?:

```swift
@MainActor class ThumbnailsViewModel1: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var thumbnails: [String] = []
    private let dataSource: ThumbnailDataSource1
    
    init() { dataSource = ThumbnailDataSource1() }
    
    
    public func fetchThumbnails(for cnt: Int) async {
        thumbnails = [String](repeating: "-1", count: cnt)
        
        let stream = dataSource.getThumbnails(cnt: cnt)
        
        for await (i, image) in stream {
            print("!", image)
            thumbnails[i] = image
        }
    }
}


actor ThumbnailDataSource1 {
    nonisolated func getThumbnails(cnt: Int) -> AsyncStream<(Int, String)> {
        return AsyncStream<(Int, String)> { continuation in
            let task = Task {
                for i in 0..<cnt {
                    print(i, "yield")
                    continuation.yield((i, await self.generatePdfThumbnail(i)))
                }
                continuation.finish()
            }
            continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func generatePdfThumbnail(_ i: Int) -> String {
        return "thumb_\(i)"
    }
}
```

```swift
@MainActor class ThumbnailsViewModel2: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var thumbnails: [String] = []
    private let dataSource: ThumbnailDataSource2
    
    init() { dataSource = ThumbnailDataSource2() }
    
    public func fetchThumbnails(for cnt: Int) async {
        thumbnails = [String](repeating: "-1", count: cnt)
        
        let stream = AsyncStream<(Int, String)> { continuation in
            let task = Task {
                for i in 0..<cnt {
                    print(i, "yield")
                    continuation.yield((i, await self.dataSource.generatePdfThumbnail(i)))
                }
                continuation.finish()
            }
            continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
        
        for await (i, image) in stream {
            print("!", image)
            thumbnails[i] = image
        }
    }
}

actor ThumbnailDataSource2 {
    func generatePdfThumbnail(_ i: Int) -> String {
        return "thumb_\(i)"
    }
}
```

When I call `viewModel.fetchThumbnails(for: 5)`, each results are:

```
// ThumbnailsViewModel1
0 yield
1 yield
2 yield
3 yield
4 yield
! thumb_0
! thumb_1
! thumb_2
! thumb_3
! thumb_4
```

```
// ThumbnailsViewModel2
0 yield
1 yield
! thumb_0
2 yield
! thumb_1
3 yield
! thumb_2
4 yield
! thumb_3
! thumb_4
```

Why does the first one(`ThumbnailsViewModel1`) use the value after `finish()` instead of using it every `yield()`?
Does the stream creation location make sense? I thought both codes would give the same result.

I think the first one is structurally correct, but the result I want is the second one.
I want it to reflect on the view whenever each thumbnail is loaded.

Comment: Technically, per [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md) the first, with non-isolated function runs on “generic executor associated with no actor” (i.e., not actor isolated, on some background thread), whereas the latter runs on the current actor (the main actor in this example). The practical implication is immaterial, because as soon as you replace your `generatePdfThumbnail` with something asynchronous, the resulting behaviors will be largely indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're only seeing a difference here because the print statements are running on separate actors, and you're also printing before the suspension point. You're also not really doing anything that would require async code, since your generate thumbnail code returns instantly.

It's more useful when trying to learn these things by doing something like `try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))` inside your code to simulate some actual work being done. If you make your thumbnail generation method `async` and include a sleep, you get pretty similar results from both code setups.

Unrelated to your question, but the code you've written is using the continuation variant of `AsyncStream`, which is really for wrapping non-async code into an async sequence. You would be better served using the unfolding variant:

```
nonisolated func getThumbnails(cnt: Int) -> AsyncStream<(Int, String)> {
    var index = 0
    return AsyncStream {
        defer { index += 1}
        if index == cnt {
            return nil
        }
        return (index, await self.generatePdfThumbnail(index))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I found the problem. Actually, when I make it async and put `sleep()`, the two results work the same.

Is it okay if I ask you an additional question?  
The `generateThumbnail()` I'm trying to do is actually quite short tasks, but I wanted to load them quickly by performing them in parallel, and reflect the loaded thumbnails in the view right away, but it doesn't work.  
Maybe my approach is wrong?

Comment: To perform tasks in parallel, use a task group.

Comment: @cyj89317 - If you are trying to achieve parallel execution, a `for` loop and an `AsyncSequence`/`AsyncStream` is not the natural pattern. Generally, we reach for [task groups](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Tasks-and-Task-Groups) when we're trying to achieve parallel execution. Re “but it doesn't work”, we obviously cannot comment without seeing what you did, but that seems like it should be posted a separate question.